# java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang

Tags: java, web-services, ant

I'm getting the following error when trying to build my very simple webservice project. I've given the build.xml, my java file and path values

The class file is getting generated, but service is not getting generated.

Please help... It's bugging for a looooong time..

Thanks! :)

> CLASSPATH=C:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib
>   \webservices.jar;C:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib\ojdbc14.jar;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_18\jre\l
>   ib\rt.jar;c:\ant\apache-ant-1.5.4\lib\ant.jar;c:\ant\apache-ant-1.5.4\lib\option
>   al.jar;
>
> Path=C:\Program Files\Reflection;C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre
>   \1.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Windows Im
>   aging\;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_18\bin;c:\j2sdk1.4.2_18\bin;c:\ant\apache-ant-1.5.4\bin;
>   PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH

---

### UserModel.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UserModel
{


    Connection con=null;

    Statement st=null;
    Statement st1=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String nm,age,course,address,mob,IdNum1;
    int IdNum,id;
    int x;
    int check=0;
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList eptylist=new ArrayList();
    UserModel() 
    {
    }

    public int insert(String name,String age,String course,String address,int Mob) throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 

    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.142.22:40401:MKTMRM9","mrm2","Marms*123.");

          st=con.createStatement();

          x= st.executeUpdate("insert into student values(seqno.nextval,'"+name+"','"+age+"','"+course+"','"+address+"','"+Mob+"')");

          if(x==1)
        {
        st1=con.createStatement();       
         rs=st.executeQuery("select seqno.currval from student");

          while(rs.next())
          {   

              IdNum=rs.getInt(1);

          }
        return IdNum;

        }
               else
        return 0;

    }   

    public ArrayList getDetails(int id1) throws  SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.142.22:40401:MKTMRM9","mrm2","Marms*123.");
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student where StudentId="+id1);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            check++;
            id=rs.getInt(1);
            nm=rs.getString(2);
            age=rs.getString(3);
            course=rs.getString(4);
            address=rs.getString(5);
            mob=rs.getString(6);

        }

        list.add(new Integer(id));
        list.add(nm);
        list.add(age);
        list.add(course);
        list.add(address);
        list.add(mob);
        if(check!=0)
        return list;
        else 
        return eptylist; 
    }

}
```

---

### build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<project name="WebServiceServer" default="create" basedir=".">

<taskdef name="servicegen" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.servicegen.ServiceGenTask"/>


<property name="src" value=".\src"/>
<property name="build" value=".\build"/>
<property name="namespace" value="http://localhost:7001/UserModel"/>

<target name="create">

<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includes="**/*.java">
</javac>


<servicegen
    destEar="myWebServer.ear"
    warName="mywebserver.war"
    contextURI="WebServiceServer">

    <service
        javaClassComponents="UserModel"
        targetNamespace="${namespace}"
        serviceName="UserModel"
        serviceURI="/UserModel"
        generateTypes="True"
        expandMethods="True"
        style="rpc">
    </service>

    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${build}"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        <pathelement path="{lib}/ojdbc14.jar"/>
    </classpath>

</servicegen>

</target>

</project>
```

---

### error from console - while ant is run

```
    Buildfile: build.xml

    create:
        [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Documents and Settings\344756\New\MyWe
    b\WebServiceServer\build
    [servicegen] Generating service "UserModel" ...
    [servicegen] java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
    [servicegen]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:524)
    [servicegen]    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader
    .java:123)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass
    (GenericClassLoader.java:476)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(Gene
    ricClassLoader.java:181)
    [servicegen]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
    [servicegen]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(Gene
    ricClassLoader.java:223)
    [servicegen]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)

    [servicegen]    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [servicegen]    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.codegen.Compiler.loadCla
    ss(Compiler.java:641)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.codegen.Compiler.addToMa
    pping(Compiler.java:450)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile
    (Compiler.java:175)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMappingBuilder.ma
    pClass(XSDTypeMappingBuilder.java:89)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMappingBuilder.ma
    pClass(XSDTypeMappingBuilder.java:102)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.TypeMappingBuilderBase.a
    ddMapping(TypeMappingBuilderBase.java:180)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.autotype.ComponentAutoTyper
    .addMapping(ComponentAutoTyper.java:88)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.autotype.ComponentAutoTyper
    .mapComponent(ComponentAutoTyper.java:141)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.autotype.JavaAutoTyper.run(
    JavaAutoTyper.java:81)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.servicegen.ServiceGenTask.r
    unAutoTyper(ServiceGenTask.java:367)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.servicegen.ServiceGenTask.g
    enerateService(ServiceGenTask.java:313)
    [servicegen]    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.servicegen.ServiceGenTask.e
    xecute(ServiceGenTask.java:181)
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:341)
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:309)
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:336)
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1339)

    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1255
    )
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:609)
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:196)
    [servicegen]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:235)

    BUILD FAILED
    file:C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/344756/New/MyWeb/WebServiceServer/build.xml:2
    0: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang

    Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Which version Weblogic are you using? Meh ... I see, it is 8.1 :D Missed it before. Then the question is, what version of JDk are you using? Because on your path you have 3 different JREs defined. What is your JAVA_HOME variable pointing to? It is most probably an error with conflicting JDKs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What package are your own classes in?

This error happens because it's forbidden to put your own classes in the package `java.lang`. It looks like you are trying to compile a class that's in the package `java.lang`.

If your own classes are not in a package at all (you don't have a `package` statement at the top of your source files), then put them in a package.

Comment: first it got solved... Now I'm still getting the same error, even after putting my class in a package.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure your project package name is not start with Java or javax, try to use the following way:

When I run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Command in CLI, it shows build success, when I use Eclipse compile project, it shows

> java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang.annotation

But my parnter project was right, I think it's IDE or compile environment problem, when I downgrade jdk version from 1.8x to 1.7x, the problem is gone.